# Installing libavl for C

Tags: c, gnu

I am VERY new to C programming!

I want to use the GNU libavl library (http://adtinfo.org).  How do I install this so it can be imported with a #include statement?

Comment: compile it and install it.  Use your OS package manager?  You didn't say what OS you are using so it's hard to say

Comment: I am using CentOS but not on a machine I have root access to.

Comment: When making, I get the error: header.h:16:21: error: sys/avl.h: No such file or directory

Comment: You can download the source code for the library, install it in your home directory and then set CFLAGS and LDFLAGS at the installed path.

Comment: How do I set these flags?

Comment: I have downloaded and unzipped the source code into my project directory.  What next?

Comment: does it have a ./configure file? if so run it.  Then run make. You may also need to specify a --prefix or similar option to tell it where to install